# ErrorException undefined array key "GET"

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, routes, undefined

I was running my Laravel application and got this error suddenly, and I'm not sure of how to solve this. I was running this on the server. Here is the detailed exception that I was getting.

> Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError
> C:\xampp\htdocs\redprixx\routes\api.php:19

**api.php**

```
Route::get('/', function (Router $router) {
    return collect($router->getRoutes()->getRoutesByMethod()["GET"])
        ->map(function ($value, $key) {
        return url($key);
    })->values();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at [the documentation](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollectionInterface.html#method_getRoutesByMethod).

`getRoutesByMethod` takes the method name **as an argument**.

It **doesn't** return an associative array of all method names.

```
getRoutesByMethod("GET")
```

Comment: so what change am i suppose to make?

Comment: @DrishtiBatra — The one in the example I gave in this answer